# TrueSDK for iOS directs to 404 website

Tags: ios, truesdk

I have implemented a simple app implementing TrueSDK, using a storyboard I added a TCProfileRequestButton but when I click on the button it takes me to a website thus I can't fetch the Truecaller profile. I have Truecaller installed and followed the installation guide on https://github.com/truecaller/ios-sdk

[image]

Answer (score 0):

TrueSDK uses universal links for communication between your app and Truecaller, that's why when you make a request from your app which opens Truecaller it will show a confirmation screen with a forward link on top right.

[image]

And clicking on that link will take you to the 404 page. This is an expected scenario with universal links. Moreover once you visited that website you will notice all of your requests will end up in that page but not in the Truecaller app, strange right? The way to overcome that is to swipe down on that website, it will show you a top bar with an open button.

[image]

Clicking on that button takes you to Truecaller and your request will be handled as regularly. From that on subsequent requests should take you to Truecaller app.